# OBS is not working with Wayland display server

Tags: xorg, 17.10, wayland, obs-studio

I have installed `Ubuntu 17.10.` Now i found that the `OBS Studio` recording software is not working with `Wayland display server`. It shows black screen and mouse pointer on the record screen. When I'm switching back to `X.org` it works perfect.

Could anyone advise ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*OBS Studio* will not work without Xorg, as it directly talks to X11 in order to perform screen recording. There is already an [open bug](https://obsproject.com/mantis/view.php?id=719) on the issue of recording under Wayland sessions, on the bug tracker.

You *may* be able to run the app under Xwayland and force `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` for OBS STudio, but there is no guarantees it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This challenge can potentially be resolve using either **[obs-xdg-portal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/feaneron/obs-xdg-portal)** or **[obs-gnome-screencast](https://github.com/fzwoch/obs-gnome-screencast)** free and open source plugins.

Attribution & details at https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/running-obs-in-wayland.32165/post-492672

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit here on how to install and ideally why this helps? It's preferable for answers to avoid heavy reliance on external links